# Predicting a timeseries that includes categorical and numeric data

Tags: predictive-modeling

Given the following properties in a dataset:

1. Type Of Work `[T1,T2,T3,...Ti]`
2. Measurment Unit `[U1,U2,U3,...Ui]`
3. Number `<int>`
4. Date `<datetime>`
5. Status `[S1,S2,S3,...Si]`

What can i use to predict the `Status` in a given `Date`?

Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are time series models that are called "dynamic regression models." These can include forecast distance models like linear models or tree-based methods.

While it is possible to do classification with time series models, it is rarer still to do multiclass classification for time series. If you have a high number of classes to predict, it might be difficult.